# Curve Control With PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, qwidget, maya

Is there any curve control in pyqt?, I have attached a image which is based on maya gradientControl. I am looking some thing similar with pyqt where I want to edit the curve and each edit should trigger some signal.Right now I can use sip and I can wrap maya gradientControl in to my pyqt window but its really not working as expected. Here is the code what I am trying. Its just a QWidget so its very hard to find what happening when I am adding a point on curve .

```
import os
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.mel as mel
import maya.OpenMayaUI as mui
import sys
import sip
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, uic
baseUI = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "range_ctrl.ui")
baseUIClass, baseUIWidget = uic.loadUiType(baseUI)

def getMayaWindow():
    windowPointer = mui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return sip.wrapinstance(long(windowPointer), QtCore.QObject)

def convertToQT(controlName):
    controlPoniter = mui.MQtUtil.findControl(controlName)
    if controlPoniter is not None:
        return sip.wrapinstance(long(controlPoniter), QtCore.QObject)

class MayaRangeCtrl(baseUIWidget, baseUIClass):
    def __init__(self, parent=getMayaWindow()):
        super(baseUIWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.setObjectName("mayaRangeCtrl")
        self.setWindowTitle("Range Control")
        self.p1_vbox = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.range_ctr = cmds.gradientControlNoAttr( 'mayaaaa', h=90)
        mayaQTObj = convertToQT(self.range_ctr)
        self.p1_vbox.addWidget(mayaQTObj)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.frame)
        self.show()

def main():
    myWindow = MayaRangeCtrl()

def run():
    main()
```

And here is the screen capture.

[image]

And the ui contain a mian window and a QFrame with.
Here is the maya [documentation](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2013/en_us/CommandsPython/gradientControlNoAttr.html)

But I am looking some pure QT widgets or some idea how we can implement this. I tried with QPolygon but no idea how we can manipulate control point run time. any idea ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think adding callback will be a solution for now, but it will be nice to know that if any one know any widget something similar to this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the gradient control is written in the C++ side of the maya code, there is no public interface to it as a PyQt4 widget as you might have already discovered (and as far as I know).

What sip will give you is a QWidget reference that lets you reparent and place it within your app as you desire. But as for working with it from there on, your best bet is to just connect up to the [python commands callbacks for the gradient control](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/CommandsPython/gradientControlNoAttr.html)

```
cmds.gradientControlNoAttr(self.range_ctr, e=True, changeCommand=self.myCallback)
```

If the available callbacks for the `gradientControlNoAttr` are not enough for you, then I am afraid you will have to roll your own custom widget using your own paint events (or using the QGraphics classes).

Comment: callbacks not really working for me. I am thinking about writing a widget myself but not sure where I want to start.

Comment: I think callbacks will work, but control over widget is limited. Issue is if I want to query the total changes from the widget like how many points added like that its very difficult.

Comment: It doesn't seem too difficult. You can either use the optionVar to just get a full string rep of the curve, or track the changes using the callback. For the most part it is like a widget with a crappier attribute interface.

Comment: True except the flexibility and speed sip wrap is fine.

Comment: Well ya you need the sip wrapped QWidget no matter what to be able to put it into your own layout and reparent it. But its not like the sip object will be of much use beyond that.